# How to get all the data of a table using group By (year) in a laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have table called salary archieves, where i used to store all salaries of a month for a specific year. **Now i want to retrieve all the months of a year**. Now if i use groupBy then i ill get my desired results but it only shows the one rows. **for example**, i have two rows in my database march and may of 2019 now i want to get all the month. I tried it

```
SalaryArchive::groupBy('year')->get()
```

but i need something like this

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: try with `->groupBy("month", "year");`

Comment: it will show all the month of a year but it will create two/more headings for a year, but i need only one heading for each year

Comment: sorry, i was meaning  `->groupBy("year", "month");`

Comment: it will produce same results as previous and the problem still remains for heading of a year

Comment: in  SQL `group by YEAR,MONTH`, isn't equals to  `group by MONTH,YEAR`, please try and tell me what happen

Comment: i mean, you have a table with all the Salary, and given a year, you want all the month that has at least one entry in that table with that year right?  `SalaryArchive::where('year' , 2019)->groupBy("month")->get();` produce that result

Comment: i mean it will create two headings for a year. Like in my table i have two years like 2005 and 2006. And in 2005 i have only month salary (may), so for this situation it will ok. But for 2006 where i have two months like april and may, then according to your query it will create two headings for 2006, i hope you will inderstand what i am trying to say

Comment: yes something like that. but what if i have multiple years like 2019, 2018 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first you need to find all the year in your database, and than, fetch the month for each year, so something like:

```php
$years=SalaryArchive::groupBy('year')->select('year')->get();
$monthOnYear = array();
foreach($years as $year) $monthOnYear[$year->year] = SalaryArchive::where('year',$year->year)->groupBy('month')->select('month')->get();
```

and then, to access it properly on your view you can do something like :

```php
@foreach($monthOnYear as $year => $months)
   Year : {{ $year }}
   Months:
   @foreach($months as $month) 
       {{$month->month }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

obviously with a proper html css styling

Comment: Illegal offset type

in SalarysheetController.php line 28

Comment: at which line refers to?

Comment: sorry forgot to add this

Comment: $monthOnYear[$year] = SalaryArchive::where('year',$year)->groupBy('month')->get();

Comment: now the error will gone and year is ok but the month is missing

Comment: what you mean with missing? i've edited the answer again

Comment: yes i trid the  latest one but also months is not showing

Comment: Dd($monthOnYear) after the foreach what return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202463/discussion-between-albertosinigaglia-and-tanvir-ahmed).